# commutivity of suspension and quotient space

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homotopy-theory, geometric-topology

Let $(A,A_0)$ be a $CW$-pair such that $A_0$ is a $CW$-subcomplex of $A$.

Let $\Sigma$ be the suspension.

Is $\Sigma(A/A_0)$ homotopy equivalent to $\Sigma A/\Sigma A_0$ or not?

Comment: In a convenient category of pointed spaces, the reduced suspension is left adjoint to taking the loop space, so it preserves colimits, so in particular pushouts and hence quotients as well. Note that you get even a homeomorphism in this setting and not just a homotopy equivalence.

Comment: @archipelago: This is an answer.